# why my chart update function doest seem to do anything?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i dont know why chart update doesnt work when destroy() is working fine.maybe it is becouse it is in functions and it is later exported idk

```
let labelArr = [];
let dataArr = [];

let data = {
  labels: labelArr,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: dataArr,
      label: "# of Amount",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#01a001",
      backgroundColor: "#01a001",
    },
  ],
};

let config = {
  type: "line",
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

function initChart(currentAccount) {
  currentAccount.transactions.forEach((t) => {
    const dateReady = currentUser.dateCreator(t.date);
    labelArr.push(dateReady);
    dataArr.push(t.amount);
  });
}

let chartUI = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);

function destroy(chartUI) {
  chartUI.data.datasets[0].data = [];
  chartUI.data.labels = [];
  labelArr = [];
  dataArr = [];
  chartUI.destroy();
}

function render(currentAccount, chartUI) {
  chartUI = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);

  currentAccount.transactions.forEach((t) => {
    const dateReady = currentUser.dateCreator(t.date);
    labelArr.push(dateReady);
    dataArr.push(t.amount);

    chartUI.data.datasets[0].data = dataArr;
    chartUI.data.labels = labelArr;
  });
  chartUI.update();
}
```

i want to update it on click like that:

```
export const initSettings = function (currentAccount) {
  initChart(currentAccount);
};

export const updateUI = function (currentAccount) {
  destroy(chartUI);
  render(currentAccount, chartUI);

};
```

i expect to update but instead of it i get canvas is already in use

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab eius esse repudiandae maxime, velit expedita id temporibus dicta consequatur eum.
```

i expect to update but instead of it i get canvas is already in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is in the function `render`. You send the `chartUI` to the function as an argument and then inside the function you assign it a `new Chart`. Thus, the value of `chartUI` in the function and the value outside are different (you probably assumed the assigned value will be available outside the scope of the function, like it's the case with references in other programming languages).

Then, the `destroy` function is always called on the same `chartUI` object, and has no effect in actually destroying the real active `chartUI` which was created in `render`.

You can verify this by logging `chartUI.canvas` in the `destroy` function - you'll see that the first time you get the canvas element from the html, but the second time the canvas is `null` - that's because the object referenced by `chartUI` is the same from the previous call and not the new one created by `new Chart`.

So, a quick fix would be to add a `return chartUI;` at the end of the function `render`:

```js
function render(currentAccount, chartUI) {
   chartUI = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
//...................
   chartUI.update();
   return chartUI;
}
```

and then recover the newly created chart object with:

```js
chartUI = render(currentAccount, chartUI);
```

in `updateUI`; [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39sr2xjv/).

However, **the whole destroy and recreate pattern is not required** for the type of data you are using (and in my experience hardly anytime actually); it also results in a non-smooth visual transition.

It is sufficient to just assign new data and call `update`, like in this snippet:

```js
let t0 = Date.now();
const currentAccountGen = ()=>{t0 += 2*24*1000*3600; return {
    transactions: Array.from({length: 10},
        (_, i)=>({date: t0+i*24*1000*3600, amount: 10+2*Math.random()+3*Math.cos(i/10*Math.PI)}))
}};

let labelArr = [];
let dataArr = [];

let data = {
    labels: labelArr,
    datasets: [
        {
            data: dataArr,
            label: "# of Amount",
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#01a001",
            backgroundColor: "#01a001",
        },
    ],
};

let config = {
    type: "line",
    data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: "time",
            },
            y: {
            //    beginAtZero: false, // default
            },
        },
    },
};

const chartUI = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);

function render(currentAccount, chartUI) {
    labelArr = [];
    dataArr = [];
    currentAccount.transactions.forEach((t) => {
        const dateReady = /*currentUser.dateCreator*/(t.date);
        labelArr.push(dateReady);
        dataArr.push(t.amount);
    });
    chartUI.data.datasets[0].data = dataArr;
    chartUI.data.labels = labelArr;
    chartUI.update();
}

render(currentAccountGen(), chartUI);
const hi = setInterval(function(){
    render(currentAccountGen(), chartUI);
}, 1000)

function stop(){
    clearInterval(hi);
    document.querySelector('#stopBut').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id='stopBut' onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<div style="height:250px">
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort for solving my problem. the one thing is the correct result on my chart but second more important is that i understood why it wasnt working. so appreciate brother :)