# Simple example for plotting purchase data (time vs value) via Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am a beginner with Chart.js and I am trying to plot the following data:

```
const purchaseData = [
                    { name: 'Item A', value: 120, timestamp: '2013-03-15T09:30:00Z' },
                    { name: 'Item B', value:  85, timestamp: '2014-05-20T14:45:00Z' },
                    { name: 'Item C', value: 200, timestamp: '2015-08-10T11:00:00Z' },
                    // ... more data ...
                    { name: 'Item X', value:  75, timestamp: '2016-01-05T16:20:00Z' }
                ];

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); // defined in the HTML code, not shown here

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: purchaseData.map(item => ({ x: new Date(item.timestamp), y: item.value })),
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'month'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My data have been obtained at irregular time intervals. I would like to display them as a line, where the x-axis represents time (say, from 2013-01 to 2016-12) and the y-axis shows the value of the purchase.

What is an example to make that work?

Regrettably, I have not found any (working) examples on the internet for this.

Comment: Look at the samples for [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html) and the following.; also check [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html), esp. the introductory part about including an adapter. You can find here on SO several posts with full code snippets on questions about chart.js time axes.

Comment: Well, I am aware of this, but unfortunately they do not provide minimal working examples: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html

Comment: The examples on chart.js are working - live, you can even edit them on the site. The presentation is indeed sub-optimal as the code is artificially split in several tabs, but they are easy to combine. If you want a frame example you can find some here on SO, as I said, some even in my own answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76565669/16466946) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193288/16466946)

Answer (score 1):

To display time on the X axis, you'll need both a date library and the [corresponding adapter](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters)

Here's an example using both [luxon.js](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon) and [chartjs-adapter-luxon](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon)

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

const cfg = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [{
            x: "2013-03-15T09:30:00Z",
            y: 120
          },          
          {
            x: "2014-05-20T14:45:00Z",
            y: 85
          },
          {
            x: "2015-08-10T11:00:00Z",
            y: 200
          },
          {
            x: "2015-09-10T11:00:00Z",
            y: 65
          },         
          {
            x: "2015-10-10T11:00:00Z",
            y: 175
          },
          {
            x: "2015-11-10T11:00:00Z",
            y: 120
          },        
          {
            x: "2015-12-10T11:00:00Z",
            y: 135
          },
          {
            x: "2015-12-25T11:00:00Z",
            y: 55
          },       
          {
            x: "2015-12-31T11:00:00Z",
            y: 150
          },       
          {
            x: "2016-01-05T16:20:00Z",
            y: 75
          },
        ],
      label:'A',
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {    
      x: {
        type: "time",
      }
    }
  }
};

const myLine = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

PS : You can also use Epoch and Unix timestamps in milliseconds as x value